# passing a long dict into aggfunc pandas python pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a very long pivot table using pandas.

I import a .csv file, creating the dataframe df. The .csv file looks like:

```
LOC,surveyor_name,test_a,test_b
A,Bob,FALSE,FALSE
A,Bob,TRUE,TRUE
B,Bob,TRUE,FALSE
B,Ryan,TRUE,TRUE
```

I have the basic pivot table setup here, creating the pivot on index LOC

```py
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['surveyor_name'], index=['LOC'],aggfunc={'surveyor_name': np.count_nonzero})
```

I would like to pass into the aggfunc section a dictionary for each column heading

I created a csv with the list of column headings and the aggregation function, i.e:

```
a,b
surveyor_name, np.count_nonzero
test_a,np.count_nonzero
test_b,np.count_nonzero
```

I create a dataframe and convert this dataframe to a dict here:

```py
keys = pd.read_csv('keys.csv')
x = keys.to_dict()
```

I now have object x that I want to enter into aggfunc, but it is at this point I can't move foward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue with this came in two parts.

Firstly the creation of the dict was not correct.

```py
x= dict(zip(keys['a'],keys['b']))
```

Secondly, instead of `np.count_nonzero` the use of `nunique` worked.